# colorbox cannot apply on dynamic appended html element

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

I am implementing the colorbox plugin like [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) .

In following html, image can apply the colorbox plug-in and pop up original image successfully.

```
<div id="SHOWPIC">
<span style='text-align:center;margin:3px;'>
    <a href='images/cartoon.png' style='position:relative;' rel='external' class='group1' >
        <img src='images/cartoon.png' width='250' height='150' />
    </a>
</span>
```

However, when same html code loaded from jquery append function, it loss the functionality of colorbox .

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#SHOWPIC").append("<span style='text-align:center;margin:3px;'><a href='images/cartoon.png' style='position:relative;' rel='external' class='group1' ><img src='images/cartoon.png' width='250' height='150' /></a></span>");

});
```

any solution for this?

Comment: Are you calling the method to apply colorbox AFTER appending the HTML  in JS?

Comment: I agree that is the problem, unfortunately the image have to be loaded in this way, and I dont have the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

what if you do like this ?

```
$("#SHOWPIC").html("<span style='text-align:center;margin:3px;'><a href='images/cartoon.png' style='position:relative;' rel='external' class='group1' ><img src='images/cartoon.png' width='250' height='150' /></a></span>");
```

Comment: it still same and cannot trigger the colorbox function

Comment: could u give some fiddle ? It's hard to understand ur issue

Answer (score 0):

You should assign Colorbox after you have appended the elements you are trying to bind an event to.  For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#SHOWPIC").append("<span style='text-align:center;margin:3px;'><a href='images/cartoon.png' style='position:relative;' rel='external' class='group1' ><img src='images/cartoon.png' width='250' height='150' /></a></span>");
    $('.group1').colorbox();
});
```

I'm sure that you have a way of doing this, but in the rare instance where that would be difficult for whatever reason, then you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).one('click', '.group1', function(){
        $('.group1').colorbox();
        $(this).click();
    });
});
```